# Exceptional Handling in Spring MVC

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, exception

How do we handle exceptions in Spring MVC while building a web project? Does Validation checks enough for handling any error?

Answer (score 0):

In handle method scope, you can use validation checks to assure the parameter is correct and has suitable range.

Goballly, if there is some exceptions which are not catched by any application functions, the @ControllerAdvice is good to deal with such exceptions.  You know much details by refering this page [exception-handling-in-spring-mvc](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)